# Me gustaría saber qué tengo mal en este código Python

Tags: python

quería que me ayudasen a resolver el problema que tengo con este código Python. En base a los parámetros que he definido en la función tengo que determinar si una persona tiene un peso normal o tiene sobrepeso. Los parametros que he puesto son los correctos, pero todos me dan sobrepeso. Algo tengo que haber hecho mal en el código.
gracias de antemano.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/content/datostest.csv.csv")
df

for i in range(len(df)):
  bmi=df['bmi'][i].replace(',','.')
  edad=df['edad'][i]
  sexo=df['sexo'][i]

def PESO(IMC):
  if sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 24 and float(bmi) <= 23.2:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 24 and float(bmi) > 23.2:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 34 and float(bmi) <= 25.225:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 34 and float(bmi) > 25.225:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 49 and float(bmi) <= 28:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 49 and float(bmi) > 28:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 64 and float(bmi) <= 32:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad <= 64 and float(bmi) > 32:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad >= 65 and float(bmi) <= 30.7:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'MUJER' and edad >= 65 and float(bmi) > 30.7:
    return "sobrepeso"

  if sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 24 and float(bmi) <= 25.241:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 24 and float(bmi) > 25.241:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 34 and float(bmi) <= 27.171:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 34 and float(bmi) > 27.171:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 49 and float(bmi) <= 28.82:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 49 and float(bmi) > 28.82:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 64 and float(bmi) <= 29.95:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad <= 64 and float(bmi) > 29.95:
    return "sobrepeso"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad >= 65 and float(bmi) <= 29.9:
    return "normal"
  elif sexo == 'HOMBRE' and edad >= 65 and float(bmi) > 29.9:
    return "sobrepeso"

df["Category"]= df["ID"].apply(PESO)
resultados_test=df[["ID","Category"]]
df.drop(['edad','peso', 'talla', 'sexo', 'provincia', 'ID', 'bmi', 'bmicod', 'edadcod'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.to_csv("resultados_tests.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: debe enviar el `sexo` dado que el `sexo` es asignado en la ultima interaccion del bucle `def PESO(sexo,IMC):`

Comment: En el bucle `for` las variables `bmi`, `edad` y `sexo`, siempre quedan asignadas con los valores de la última fila del `csv`; que es probable que  coincida con `sobrepeso`...

Answer (score 1):

Como te dijeron en el comentario, el bucle `for` itera los datos antes de enviarle algo a alguna función, por lo que los valores `bmi`, `edad` y `sexo` quedan mapeados al último registro del dataframe.

Por otro lado, esa función no es escalable y es más difícil de mantener. Se podría reescribir en algo que mantenga los datos independientes de la lógica, y de esta manera puedes agregar, quitar o modificar los parámetros fácilmente.

```py
def PESO(bmi, edad, sexo):
    data = {
        'MUJER': {24:23.2, 34:25.225, 49:28, 64:32, 65:30.7},
        'HOMBRE': {24:25.241, 34:27.171, 49:28.82, 64:29.95, 65:29.9}
    }
    for k, v in data[sexo].items():
        if edad <= k:
            return "normal" if bmi <= v else "sobrepeso"
    # Si la edad es mayor que el último elemento (65), entonces:
    return "normal" if bmi <= data[sexo].popitem()[-1] else "sobrepeso"
```

Y para usarla solo basta con enviarle los 3 parámetros:

```py
personas = [
    [23.8, 32, 'MUJER'], 
    [27.1, 32, 'MUJER'],
    [32.2, 70, 'HOMBRE'],
    [28.6, 70, 'HOMBRE']
]

for p in personas:
    bmi, edad, sexo = p
    print(PESO(bmi, edad, sexo))

# Resultado: normal - sobrepeso - sobrepeso - normal
```